# Rust different types when referring to same file

Tags: enums, rust

I've come across a problem while attempting to use a custom enum across multiple files in Rust. I would expect to be able to write one file that contains this enum and reference it from multiple files (file_a.rs runs a function that returns a Shape enum, main.rs matches the type, but it expects types::Shape and finds a file_a::types::Shape). The outcome I expect is that both are of type types::Shape, but this does not seem to be the case.

In the past, to fix this problem, I have simply put all of the code that creates these conflicts into the same file. This does not seem like a proper solution, and especially not a professional one.

I have not been able to find any articles or questions that deal with using enums across different files in the way that I am (please direct me to them if you can).

**How can I use an enum across multiple files while keeping it's type the same across all of them?**

Here is a small example that demonstrates the problem. The errors occur in main.rs in the match statement.

Directory structure:

```
src
|    main.rs
|____core
|   |    types.rs
|   |    file_a.rs
```

/src/main.rs:

```rust
#[path = "./core/types.rs"]
mod types;
use types::*;

#[path = "./core/file_a.rs"]
mod file_a;
use file_a::*;

fn main()
{
    match return_a_shape()
    {
        Shape::CIRCLE => println!("circle"),        // expected enum `file_a::types::Shape`, found enum `types::Shape`
        Shape::SQUARE => println!("square"),        // expected enum `file_a::types::Shape`, found enum `types::Shape`
        Shape::TRIANGLE => println!("triangle"),    // expected enum `file_a::types::Shape`, found enum `types::Shape`
        _ => println!("unknown shape"),
    }
}
```

/src/core/file_a.rs:

```rust
mod types;
use types::*;

pub fn return_a_shape() -> Shape
{
    return Shape::CIRCLE;
}
```

/src/types.rs:

```rust
pub enum Shape
{
    SQUARE,
    CIRCLE,
    TRIANGLE,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just studying rust, but as far as I understand, the problem here is not in the `enum`, but in the `mod`. This keyword turns one module into a submodule of another module. So, when you make `types` into a submodule of both `file_a` and `main`, it is imported twice as two different modules.

You can delete `mod types;` line from the `file_a.rs` and import it from parent module as `use super::types::*;`.

```rust
use super::types::*;

pub fn return_a_shape() -> Shape
{
    return Shape::CIRCLE;
}
```

---

Or you can import `types` module into the `file_a` but not in the `main` module, and reexport it:

file_a.rs

```rust
pub mod types; // Import types as a submodule and reexport it
use types::*;

pub fn return_a_shape() -> Shape
{
    return Shape::CIRCLE;
}
```

main.rs

```rust
#[path = "./core/file_a.rs"]
mod file_a;
use file_a::*;
use file_a::types::*; // Use types submodule from the file_a module

fn main()
{
    match return_a_shape()
    {
        Shape::CIRCLE => println!("circle"),
        Shape::SQUARE => println!("square"),
        Shape::TRIANGLE => println!("triangle"),
        _ => println!("unknown shape"),
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a quick response! This was indeed the solution to my problem. My idea of modules and scope were not correct, and seeing this example work and going back to look at the [docs for super and self](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/mod/super.html#super-and-self) helped me understand it better.